# Writing generic functions for all types of Django models

Tags: python, django

What I need to achieve is best described by example. Imagine that I have multiple models (let's say, model `Task` and model `Animals`) that have a field named `foo` and my goal is to perform identical set of MySQL transactions for all of these models. For example, I want to increment by one all the `foos` of a given instance along with subsequent instances (with larger id's). Something like:

```
def example_view(instance):
    instance.foo = instance.foo + 1
    instance.save()
    id = instance.id
    INSTANCE_MODEL.objects.filter(id__gt = instance.id).update(foo = foo + 1)
```

The question is, is it possible in Django to write generic functions in a sense that I can use `example_view` with `Animals`, `Tasks`, etc, as long as all of them have fields mentioned in the view ? And if yes, what is the valid syntax for `INSTANCE_MODEL.objects....` ?

Comment: This is the principle called duck-typing; as long as an object responds to an interface it doesn't matter what class it is. So what, exactly, is your question?

Comment: The right syntax for `INSTANCE_MODEL` is `type(instance)` or maybe `instance._meta.model`, but I'd simply use `type()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mixin.

```
def MixIn(pyClass, mixInClass):
    pyClass.__bases__ += (mixInClass,)

class Person(..sql model class..):
   ...
class Order(..sql model class..):


class MyMixinClass(object):
     def dummy(self):
        print("This method should be visible in Person and Order classes")

# apply mixin to Person and Order
MixIn(Person, MyMixinClass)
MixIn(Order, MyMixinClass)

p = Person()
p.dummy()  # it's ok

o = Order()
o.dummy()  # it's ok
```

Generally it would be nice to define another base class derived from ..sql model.. class.

```
class MyBaseModel(..sql model class..):
    def dummy(self):
       ...

class Person(MyBaseModel):
   ...

class Order(MyBaseModel):
   ....
```

You can give it a chance in `Django`, but in `Pyramid` and `SQLAlchemy` it doesn't work for some reason (that is unknown to me), so I use simply dynamic `MixIn` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your models to increment by one all the `foo` like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ....
    foo = ....

    def increment_foo(self):
        self.foo = self.foo + 1
        self.save()
        #increment by one all the foos
        Task.objects.filter(id__gt = self.id).update(foo = foo + 1)

class Animal(models.Model):
    ....
    foo = ....

    def increment_foo(self):
        self.foo = self.foo + 1
        self.save()
        #increment by one all the foos
        Animal.objects.filter(id__gt = self.id).update(foo = foo + 1)
```

you can call it in your view with: `task_instance.increment_foo()` or `animal_instance.increment_foo()`